# Connect to own IP, iptables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

I have a set of firewall rules but the public IP address is blocked to the outside.

How would it be possible to open the public IP so that it can be connected from a web browser?

I wrote something like:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 'xx.xx.xx.xx' -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 'xx.xx.xx.xx' -j ACCEPT
```

Where 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is the public IP, but it did not work.

Comment: You inverted source and destination IPs: in the `INPUT` chain your IP is the destination (`-d`).

Comment: Ok, that worked, thanks.